# SQL Update cell with GetDate() when data in other cell in the same row changes

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL server 2012 I have a table:

```
ID      Data     Date
1       A        NULL
2       B        NULL
3       C        NULL
```

I have a function that updates values in column *Data* (I can't change this function that it will update *Date* column).
Is there any possibility to update column *Date* with value of GetDate() function if the value in column *Data* changes and only in the row where column *Data* was changed? Maybe with triggers?

Desired result:

```
ID      Data     Date
1       C        2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
2       B        NULL
3       C        NULL
```

Comment: trigger seems to be a reasonable solution, however they do add an overhead to the performance of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah a trigger is probably your best bet.  Just put one for UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tU_your_table ON your_table
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN 

UPDATE your_table
SET [Date] = GETDATE()
FROM your_table, inserted
where your_table.id = inserted.id
END
GO
```